# boost asio udp forwarder/proxy, work fine with one client but very slow with more

Tags: c++, proxy, udp, boost-asio

I try to make a program that can forward UDP packets to a specific destination. For that I choose to use the boost asio library for the network part.

I have currently two versions of the program: the first is, if I can say, stateful because the program keeps track of some information contained in the UDP packets in order to know to which endpoint forward back the response. For this version, the program use one socket to handle clients, another to forward the packets to the server and it works fine. But I prefer to forward the UDP packets without read the data they carry and this is where my problem begins.

The second version, in order to not keep track of the endpoint that send the UDP packet, use more than one socket to forward the packets to the server and rather than close them, I use a (std::)queue to store a pointer of the socket in order to use it later (the program can create new socket if the queue is empty). With this version, when I use only one client it works well, but when I add one or more clients the forwarder slowdown strongly.

Did I miss something? Have you any idea of what is the cause of the problem?

Thanks in advance

**udp_server.h**:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <queue>

class udp_server {
private:
    class udp_session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<udp_session> {
    public:
        udp_server &_udps;
        boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint _endpoint_in;
        boost::asio::ip::udp::socket *_socket_out;
        char _buffer[8800];

        udp_session(udp_server &udp_server);

        ~udp_session();

        void process(size_t bytes_transferred);

        void receiveFromNext(const boost::system::error_code &err, 
                             size_t bytes_transferred);

        void sendToPrev(const boost::system::error_code &err, 
                        size_t bytes_transferred);
    };

    boost::asio::io_service &_ios;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket _socket_in;
    std::queue<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket*> _sockets;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint _endpoint_out;

public:
    udp_server(boost::asio::io_service &ios,
               std::string host, std::string port);

    ~udp_server();

    void receive();

    void handle_receive(std::shared_ptr<udp_session> session, 
                        const boost::system::error_code &err,
                        size_t bytes_transferred);
};
```

**udp_server.cpp**:

```cpp
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

#include "udp_server.h"

udp_server::udp_session::udp_session(udp_server &udp_server) : _udps(udp_server) { }

udp_server::udp_session::~udp_session() { }

void udp_server::udp_session::process(size_t bytes_transferred) {
        if(!_udps._sockets.empty()){
            _socket_out = _udps._sockets.back();
            _udps._sockets.pop();
        }else{
            _socket_out = new boost::asio::ip::udp::socket(_udps._ios,
                                   boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(
                                           boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(), 0));
        }
        _socket_out->async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(_buffer, bytes_transferred), 
                                   _udps._endpoint_out,
                                   boost::bind(&udp_session::receiveFromNext, 
                                               shared_from_this(),           
                                               boost::asio::placeholders::error,                                
                                               boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

}

void udp_server::udp_session::receiveFromNext(const boost::system::error_code &err,
                                              size_t bytes_transferred) {
    if (!err) {
        _socket_out->async_receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(_buffer, 8800),
                                        _udps._endpoint_out,
                                        boost::bind(&udp_session::sendToPrev,
                                                    shared_from_this(),
                                                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
}

void udp_server::udp_session::sendToPrev(const boost::system::error_code &err, 
                                         size_t bytes_transferred) {
    if (!err) {
            _udps._socket_in.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(_buffer, bytes_transferred),
                                     _endpoint_in);
            _udps._sockets.emplace(_socket_out);
    }
}

udp_server::udp_server(boost::asio::io_service &ios, cs_cache &cs,
                       std::string host, int port)
                      : _ios(ios)
                      , _socket_in(ios, boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(), 3000)) {
    _endpoint_out = *boost::asio::ip::udp::resolver(ios).resolve({boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(), host, port}); 
    receive();
}

udp_server::~udp_server() { }

void udp_server::receive() {
    auto session = std::make_shared<udp_session>(*this);
    _socket_in.async_receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(session->_buffer, 8800),
                                  session->_endpoint_in,
                                  boost::bind(&udp_server::handle_receive,
                                              this,
                                              session,
                                              boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                              boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void udp_server::handle_receive(std::shared_ptr<udp_session> session, 
                                const boost::system::error_code &err,
                                size_t bytes_transferred) {
    if (!err) {
        _ios.dispatch(boost::bind(&udp_session::process, 
                                  session, 
                                  bytes_transferred));
    }
    receive();
}
```

**main.cpp**:

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include "udp_server.h"

void signal(int n) {
    std::cerr << "close" << std::endl;
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    boost::asio::io_service::work work(ios);

    udp_server udp(ios, "127.0.0.1", "6363");

    signal(SIGINT, signal);

    try {
        ios.run();
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Edit:

[test with one client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qka80.png)
[test with two clients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Efb0I.png)

Comment: Need more stats. What slow down did you measure ? How did you measure it ? Provide the measuring code as well. What is the size of the UDP socket buffer in the kernel ? Was there any packet drops (`netstat` on linux shows that)?

Comment: @Arunmu, my client report the number of packets it receives per second. its behavior is to send 1 packet then wait for a responce before sending the next one. You can find the code of the client here : https://github.com/Kanemochi/ndnperf/tree/master/java/client/src (Java). But it use a protocol in development named "Named Data Networking". I also add 2 screenshots. for your other questions, netstat report "0 packet receive errors" (netstat -s) and for the buffer size: net.core.rmem_max = 212992

Comment: The whole chain of `process` calling `async_send_to` which instead of sending calls `receive_from_next` which in turn calls `sendToPrev` is dubious. You should really reconsider this design. I don't think just for a forwarder you need to make so many async calls. Note that, async calls are not that cheap. Even `2ms` for your single client case is bit too much considering the simplicity of the requirement.

Comment: @Arunmu, the names seem weird but it is because I will chain this program with some others. The latency is due to slow packets decoding/encoding, the footprint of the forwarder is around 0.1ms. May it can help to know that: if a client sends 8 packets at a same time, the forwarder will open as many sockets as pending packets. The result reported by the client is a packet throughput of around 3500 packets/s without any drop. The issue seems to occur only with the usage of multiple (client) endpoints. I will do some research for a way to reduce the code complexity like you suggest.

Comment: `if a client sends 8 packets at a same time, the forwarder will open as many sockets as pending packets`...Why? Why can't it be done by a single socket ? I assume you don't have any ordering constraints here. If not' you can very well parallelize processing of each packet by passing it to a thread pool.

Comment: @Arunmu, yes that right, but I see that as a next step because it add some additional controls in order to have one socket per client (like a NAT) because I can't use acceptor like TCP. I thought trying to resolve this problem before going any further in the development like the ressource optimization you propose but I will give it a shot. All proposals are welcome because they can help me to improve myself (I am not very used to the boost libraries).

Comment: Sure :) It should be blazing fast with C++, else `go` or even `python` would suffice ;)